# How do I setup JAAS for a JSF website in Rational Application Developer 9.5?

Tags: jsf, jaas, ibm-rad

I have created a JSF website that requires authentication, and I've created simple authentication manually by creating a singleton class `User.java` which contains two `String`s, `username` and `password` along with a function that contacts a database to verify these credentials.

The function is called in the `Login` page when the users enters a username and password and clicks a `Login` button, and also called whenever any other page loads to prevent a user from gaining access by just typing the homepage `URL`.

I have came to realize that it would be much better to do this using `JAAS`, which will enable me to configure roles and would be simpler. I have searched but couldn't find any material to help me do this in RAD 9.5, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is not really jsf related. JAAS is independent of the UI technology

Comment: @Kukeltje I only included the JSF tag because I want to implement JAAS on a JSF website. I thought it might be related or maybe the implementation might be different somehow.